# Emailing a pivot table from a Google spreadsheet with apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

New to Apps scripts...

I have a google sheet with a pivot table in a sheet called "Rebate"

I am trying to send the pivot table in an email, but have no idea on how to do that

I managed to shoot an email out by reading other people's suggested code, but still not sure how to put the pivot table in the email boday.

below is what I get for sending email out

```
function email() {
  var message = "testing";
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() 
  MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: email,
  subject: 'test email',
  htmlBody: message});
 }
```

Any assistance is much appreciated!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by emailing the pivot table? Send its data as an attached file? Or maybe build an HTML table with this data? In any of these cases, would you consider sharing a copy of the spreadsheet, free of sensitive information?